# how to find the commit message by author?

Tags: git

How can I find the commit message by a specific author?

For example, if we are both working on a project and I want to find the line added by another author for the file `hello.java`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git blame hello.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the commit message, or for the specific line changed by the commit?

If you're looking for the message, use `git log` to see all of the commit messages. If you mean the specific code line, KingCrunch has what you want.

Comment: thanks it work but if i like to looke for specific  code line by name i try this git blame -HomePC hello.java  but is not work